# Python Open File path that changes dynamically

Tags: python, regex, file, csv

I have a file that is updated throughout the day and the name of that file changes with a time signature of when the file was updated.

e.g.

> \folder\todolist\grocerylist_2015-12-30-093000.csv

How can I open this file in python without manually updating the full file path?

Comment: Is it the only file in the directory, or are older versions kept around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module to handle this.

```
import glob
file_path = glob.glob('\\folder\\todolist\\grocerylist_*.csv')[0]
```

If there are more files and you only need the most recent, you can sort and take the last one:

```
file_path = sorted(glob.glob('\\folder\\todolist\\grocerylist_*.csv'))[-1]
```

Comment: presuming there is only one file that matches the pattern, if there are more you will need the newest created file which will involve sorting

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the python [glob](https://pymotw.com/2/glob/) module to open the file with the prefix `grocerylist_`

```
import glob
path = glob.glob('/folder/todolist/grocerylist_*.csv')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch for file creation I would recommend using something like [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html), this will always give you the latest file created that matches your pattern:

```
import sys
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
class Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, regexes):
        super(Handler, self).__init__(regexes)

    def process(self, event):
        print(event.src_path, event.event_type)


    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    pth = sys.argv[1:]
    observer = Observer()
    pth = pth[0] if pth else "./"
    observer.schedule(Handler([os.path.join(pth, "grocerylist_*.csv")]), path=pth[0] if pth else './')
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

When a file matching your pattern is created `on_created` will be called which calls `process` and you can do whatever you like in the method:

```
~$ python3 watch.py  & 
[15] 21005
padraic@home:~$ touch grocerylist_12345.csv
padraic@home:~$ ./grocerylist_12345.csv created
```

If you want to open the file just do it in process.